# dart / flutter create map with unique keys, with sublist of unique related items from a list of objects

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart

I'm trying to find a way without loops to write a class to be used to organize a list of Question objects and to create a list of sections and corresponding categories that are in the list itself

1. The input of class is a list of Questions.  Each question has a section and a category property as shown below.
   ex: `{section: 'history', category: 'South American', questionText: 'yada yada'}`)
2. I'm trying to read the list of questions, and get the unique sections and categories, and their relationship. (i.e. South American is one of the categories of history)
3. Finally, I want to end up with a Map<String, List< String >> object that uses the section names as the key and the List for the corresponding categories of the section. (I'll use this to create menu dropdowns and the like)

The following code is what I came up with, but it's heavy on for loops, and the 'sections' property is redundant since the same info is contained in the categories property as the key.

In short, how can I streamline createSectionList()  and createCategoryMap() below to identify unique values in the sections, and then identify unique values in the corresponding categories?

I created this dartpad link with the following code, and the support structures:
https://dartpad.dev/ffd899621335537d7104aabac8b524c4

```
class TBRinProgress {

  final List<Question> allQuestions;
  List<String> sections;
  Map<String, List<String>> categories;

    TBRinProgress({this.allQuestions}) {
        sections = createSectionList(allQuestions);
        categories = createCategoryMap(sections, allQuestions);
      }
    
      List<String> createSectionList(List<Question> questionList) {

        final List<String> temp = [];

        questionList.sort((a, b) => a.section.compareTo(b.section));

        for (final Question question in questionList) {
          temp.add(question.section);
        }

        final Set sectionSet = temp.toSet();
        print(sectionSet);
        return sectionSet.toList() as List<String>;

      }
    
      Map<String, List<String>> createCategoryMap(
          List<String> sections, List<Question> questions) {

        final Map<String, List<String>> mapSectionsWithCategories = {};

        for (final String section in sections) {
          final List<Question> questionOneSectionCategories =
              questions.where((element) => element.section == section).toList();
          final List<String> thisSectionCategories = [];

          for (final question in questionOneSectionCategories) {
            thisSectionCategories.add(question.category);
          }

          final Set categorySet = thisSectionCategories.toSet();
          final List<String> uniqueSectionCategories =
              categorySet.toList() as List<String>;

          uniqueSectionCategories.sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));

          mapSectionsWithCategories[section.toLowerCase()] =
              uniqueSectionCategories;

          print(mapSectionsWithCategories);
        }

        print(mapSectionsWithCategories);
        return mapSectionsWithCategories;

      }
}
```

Comment: Is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66018549/how-do-i-make-a-new-array-nested-sorted-maps) related to your question?